# Write List of IP Addresses to text file - Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text

I am in the process of parsing out all the IP Addresses from auth.log. I have the following script to parse out the ip addresses and it seems to be working fine (or at least it is capturing the IP Addresses).

```
import re 

authLog = open("auth.log", "rb")
string = authLog.read()

ipAddress = re.findall(r"[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}", string)

print ipAddress
```

What i want to do is write the IP Addresses to a text file with each IP having its own line. i.e.

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1 
etc...
```

That means I need to get rid of the quotation marks from python and the comma as well. Right now it just prints the IP Address in this format: '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1',  etc...

What would be the best method of executing this? As always, your help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Honestly, if you are going to downvote people, post why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I suggest choosing a different name for `ipAddress`. `findall` returns a list of strings, and list names are traditionally plural. How about `ipAddresses`?

You can combine a list of strings into a single delimited string using `join`. You can use a newline as a delimiter. Example:

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join(ipAddresses))
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. and I did change the name so its plural. I have to get in those good habits now.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why there are so many haters and trolls down voting normal questions. Im upvoting you to offset.

to do a newline in python usually you want to use

```
\n
```

The best way to do this however is to use a 'for' statement

```
 for val in ipAddress:
      print(val + '\n')
```

This will print each ipAddress on its own line

Comment: sorry it should be '\n'

Comment: @ Nefarii I don't know why it was down voted but I do appreciate your Help.